# htaccess redirect conflicts with existing rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have all incoming URL requests to my website transformed into GET params, so `fruits.com/apple` becomes `fruits.com/?url=apple` and my routing mechanism takes care of showing the correct view.

### .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php
RewriteRule .* index.php?url=$0 [QSA,L]
```

This works fine. However I now have some exceptions and I want these URLs redirecting to the homepage. `Redirect` conflicts with the above rule:

```
Redirect /pineapple /
Redirect /grapes /
```

This redirects to `fruits.com/?url=pineapple` instead of just `fruits.com`.

How do I do a clean redirect to `fruits.com`?

### horrible solution

I can think of one solution that's terribly inelegant for anything more than a couple of exceptions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pineapple$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/grapes$
RewriteRule .* index.php?url=$0 [QSA,L]

Redirect /pineapple /
Redirect /grapes /
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your code with this:

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(pineapple|grapes)/? /? [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php
RewriteRule .+ index.php?url=$0 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Success! I didn't need the `Options`, but your `RewriteRule` did the trick. It now works exactly how I wanted it to, so thanks for that.

Comment: You're welcome, yes I know for this simple case Options were not needed but I still provided them as I try to provide complete answers.

Answer (score 1):

On the code side of things we're less concerned about elegance and more concerned with performance.

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(pineapple|grapes)/?$
RewriteRule .* index.php?url=$0 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule (pineapple|grapes)/? / [R,L]
```

If you have access to `httpd.conf` you can use a [rewritemap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html) if you're concerned with how it looks.

Comment: Fair enough. The redirect in your solution works, but `/pineapple` and `/grapes` is still visible in the URL

Comment: Sorry, forgot the hard redirect flag.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to a RewriteRule with the R flag instead of a Redirect.  You will also use the L flag on your RewriteRule to tell Apache to move to stop processing other rules if this rule matches.  So you put this above your other rules like so

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^pineapple / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^apple / [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php
RewriteRule .* index.php?url=$0 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Sorry to say that this doesn't work. It continues on to `fruits.com/pineapple/`

Comment: Typing too fast.  Used a `/` where I should have used a `^`.  The `^` is needed to keep you from matching `fruits.com/subdir/apple`  remove it if you want to match apple anywhere and not just in the begining.